# Microcontrollers with built in HID support

Tags: usb, attiny, nrf24l01+, atmega32u4

I am trying to build a wireless gamepad for which i am using NRF24l01 module for my wireless need and for Sending data to computer i need an mcu which support to act as hid device. So far, i got Attiny85 and mcu with atmega324u. But the problem is that attiny85 has very few pins and i cannot use it as for both hid and nrf module simutaneously due to pins defficiency. And atmega324u mcu are not avialable in my country. Can anybody suggest me some mcu with built in hid support.

Answer (score 2):

The ATTiny85 doesn't support USB. You can bitbang USB using the V-USB library. Kind of a hack, but it does work. An ATMega328 (used on the UNO) can do the same thing. So the ATMega328 would be an option too (if the ATTiny85 is).

The ATMega32u4 does support USB natively, so this might be better. The ATMega32u4 is the MCU used on the Arduino Leonardo and the Arduino MICRO. Those might be available where you live.

You can also use a regular Arduino UNO. As on the UNO there is also a ATMega16u2 that does the usb-to-serial. You can reprogram this ATMega16u2 to also act as a keyboard. Like [in this project](http://mitchtech.net/arduino-usb-hid-keyboard/)